# Easy to use open source or cloud recommendation software

Tags: cloud-service, machine-learning, recommendation-engine

I'm looking for an AI based recommendation system that will learn user preferences and return personalized recommendations based on the principles of hybrid and collaborative filtering.

Tried this: https://github.com/guymorita/recommendationRaccoon it keeps on crashing with memory errors for me, since it's unmaintained I don't have the motivation to get it working.

I prefer an easy to work with open source solution, I tried https://github.com/actionml/harness/ but it seems very unready. The documentation is bad and progress is slow.

Looking at cloud solutions there's AWS Personalize and Google Recommendations AI. Haven't tried either of them, am holding out for a cheaper solution. There are frequently companies that offer cheaper variants of AWS or Google Cloud products, can anyone recommend some?

However ultimately I prefer an open source solution if possible.

Comment: Are you looking for a library to perform recommendations in the app you develop? Or as a personal tool? If a persona tool, are you OK with your preferences data being shared, or not?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul the former